# Find out large files

Tags: centos

I have a directory in my Cent OS machine where the users would drop in in all their files. I want to find out which user is dropping the large files in the folder.

Day by day this increases & would want to know the large files. Any command for that as I do not wish to check them manually.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use something like:

```
while read directory
do
    find "$directory" -size +1M -exec stat --format="%U (id: %u), file: %n" {} \;
done << EOT
/path/to/folder 1
/path/to/my folder 2
EOT
```

The `+1M` would look for files over 1M.

The stat format would show a username, its user ID and corresponding file name, for anything find would have matched.

Following up on comments, say I want to filter these on modification time, such as `find` should not match any file that got modified in the last 24 hours, then I could use:

```
find "$directory" -size +1M -mtime +1 -exec stat --format="%U (id: %u), file: %n" {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I find it for the following directory as am unable to check for the same "/aaa/bbb/ccc dddd"

Comment: I could edit my `/path/to/watch` to `/aaa/bbb/cccc/dddd`, although I'ld probably have missed your point: what do you mean, what "following" directory?

Comment: Ok. "/home/xxx/yyy zzz" is the respective directory in which I want to know the users dropping large files along with the file details. Pls advice.

Comment: Note: cccc dddd denotes "sharing folder". Its the same directory & according to your comment cccc & dddd are not different directories. When i try with the same path, it throws me an error that the directory doesn't exist. Hope you get my point!

Comment: `/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd` has a meaning, and it is not "folder `aaaa` or folder `bbbb` or folder `cccc`".

Comment: Replace /path/to/watch with that path

Comment: "find /home/p4/patent/sharing folder -size +1M -exec stat --format="%U (id: %u), file: %n" {} \;" is the command I used but the following is the result, find: `/home/p4/patent/sharing': No such file or directory
find: `folder/': No such file or directory

Comment: You would notice my find command uses double-quotes, which tells find that folder name should be processed as a single argument. Try `"/home/p4/patent/sharing folder"` instead.

Comment: (to be precise, using double quotes tells your shell, to treat it as a single argument, not `find`)

Comment: your above command helped me to filter out the large files with the user name & directories. But now I have a requirement where I need to find out the old large files to move/delete them to save space in the server. Because the files that I filtered out are the recent files which cannot be moved nor deleted.

Comment: @SYN - any updates?

Comment: It would sound the option you're looking for is `-mtime`, matching files based on modification time.

Comment: "find "$directory" -size +1M -mtime -exec stat --format="%U (id: %u), file: %n" {} \;" ---- would this be a better command?

Comment: `mtime` would expect for an argument. I have no idea what you mean by "old age", you'ld want to figure that one out. Right here and now, what you need is `man find`. If your question changed, then edit your initial post. At which point it would make sense for me to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '$3 >= 500 {print $1}'`; do find path -type f  -size +1M -user $i -exec ls -ltr {} \;; done | awk '{print $3,$NF}'
```

Above list out the files and username whose file size is greater than 1M. As checked its worked fine. Let me know the update

it will also ignore the files of system users. so only we specified condition cat `/etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '$3 >= 500 {print $1}`

Comment: that command did not work out Praveen. It just displayed the next prompt once I execute the above command.

Comment: @Rajadurai edited the command. Kindly check and let me know for any doubts

Comment: that worked but I would need the folder name which has posted the large files rather than the owner. Both also would be helpful. Tried replacing "user" with "name" but it didn't work out. So, basically I need the usernames with the folders posting large files comparing to the previous dates.